# how to include another data in api_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code:

```rb
    module Api::V1
  class ConsultanciesApiController < Api::V1::ApiController
    before_action :set_consultancy, only: [:show]

    def show
      render json: @consultancy.to_json(include: [:profiles])
    end

    private
    def set_consultancy
      @consultancy = Consultancy.find(params[:consultancy_id])
    end

  end
end
```

i have to include `:sender`, because in table consultancies i have a sender_id and i have to print the full_name not the id
how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include [multiple associations](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json#443-Multiple-associations-on-the-same-level):

```rb
render json: @consultancy.to_json(include: [:profiles, :sender])
```